# How to map AWS IP Address to Domain name to run CodeIgniter Web Application on XAMPP Apache server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

I've Hosted my Web Application on AWS ec2 server which contains XAMPP(Apache)server running. When I'm trying to run my application with IP Address it runs fine, but when I'm trying to map it with Domain name it gives me an error:

> This page isn’t working  www.mydomain.com is currently unable to
>   handle this request.  HTTP ERROR 503

**My .htaccess file is**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  #RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain\.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.my-domain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^my-domain\.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.my-domain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I created a sample file `hello.php` which working fine with my domain name. But when I'm trying to run my codeigniter application it gives an error.

**My code in httpd-vhosts.conf file:**

```
<VirtualHost www.my-domain.com>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName www.my-domain.com
    ServerAlias www.my-domain.com
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I hosted my application in root folder of XAMPP server(all files in `htdocs`).

Replace `127.0.0.1 with my-domain` and replace `AWS-IP-ADDRESS with my-domain` in `hosts` file.

Any kind of help is welcome, thanks in advance.